# catch onKeyDown MainActivity and pass keyCode to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

Thank you very much in advance for the help.

I have a ManiActivity where I need to catch the keyCode of the onKeyDown Event and pass it to a fragment.

Would you could help as I can do that?

I have the next codo from implement a event

```
 private MyStringListener listener;

    public interface MyStringListener{

        public boolean computeSomething(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);

    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (MyStringListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException castException) {
            /** The activity does not implement the listener. */
        }
    }



    public void myOnKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {


        }

    }
```

but I don't now how to do an event in the mainactivity to send the keyCode to the fragment

I hope help, Thanks

Comment: please try something yourself then ask a question here if you face some trouble...

Comment: Thanks , I already tried it and I could not make it work, I searched the internet and could not find anything that works

Comment: then you should post whatever you tried...

Comment: I have the following code in a fragment is one interface to handle an event.

Comment: private MyStringListener listener;

    public interface MyStringListener{

        public boolean computeSomething(int keyCode, KeyEvent event);

    }

Comment: @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (MyStringListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException castException) {
            /** The activity does not implement the listener. */
        }
    }

Comment: but I don't how to do an event in the mainactivity to send the keyCode to the fragment